# Finding xPath in IE Dev tools similar to $x(xPathString) console function in Firebug

Tags: debugging, xpath, selenium, firebug, ie-developer-tools

I am using with great success the $x console function in Firebug
usually i write in Firebug's console:

```
$x("//div/whatever my xpath string is")
```

Then i execute my console function and i get a result.
Does anybody know a similar function that can be used in IE Developer Tools?

Comment: how this is deal with selenium?

Comment: the common thing with selenium is that usually people who create automated tests with selenium use xpath and i assume that they use this feature for creating their xpath

Comment: Ok, I see. Not sure if IE dev tools support xpath, but you can always (or almost always) use css instead: `$("div>whatever your css string is")`

Comment: The thing is that i have an entire framework that uses xpath and there are no fixed IDs, they are dynamic. Moreover, in some cases a i have several components with the same class, but some of them have one more class that makes them be display:none;. The objects used in the framework are inherited from one another, so i need to have complex xpath expressions in order to have them genericly defined. If there really is no other way to use xpath in IE, then i'll use CSS selectors, but it seems it is working, there are only a few xpaths i used which were not correctly identified in IE.

Comment: Did you already try firebug lite for IE? http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/install-firebug-for-browsers-other-than-firefox/

Comment: using xpaths to locate elements in selenium IE is not a good idea.  there is no built in xpath engine so css selectors are much more performant, use this as proof: http://saucelabs.com/blog/index.php/2011/05/why-css-locators-are-the-way-to-go-vs-xpath/

Comment: @AJ I tried using Firebug Lite, but I wasn't able to find a way to use the $x() function that is available in Firebug (more description about this http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Command_Line_API#.24x.28xpath.29).

Comment: @Robert Evans Thanks Robert for your link I just read the post and watched the presentation and it made me think of using CSS selectors. Anyway, during the presentation i also found what i was looking for, which is Selector Gadget. It can be found at http://www.selectorgadget.com/ . So this way I can think about the complex locators which will probably remain xPath(be cause CSS selectors do not support bottom up traversing) and the others that will be CSS. Really useful information

Answer (score -1):

http://code.google.com/p/fire-ie-selenium/ - Are you looking for some thing like this?